# Tool selection with mouse in emacs for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs

After watching [this](http://www.cinsk.org/emacs/emacs-artist.html) video I decided to install the artist for emacs. I'm using http://emacsformacosx.com/ and I've been successful in using the tools provided in the artist install and they're awesome!

However, I want to know if it's possible to change and select tools like the guy in the video does, i.e. right click -> select tool. When I right click in Emacs I see nothing. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about on OSX but on my GNU/Linux machine, middle click is what brings up the tool selection menu. Is that insufficient? If so, you can manually bind `artist-mouse-choose-operation` to your key of choice.